# Tuple vs List vs Dictionary when using "in" statement

Tags: python

I have a small if statement that is checking if the variable is either of 2 values. Through testing I can see that all 3 of the following would work:

```
var = 'a'

if(var in ['a', 'b']):
  print("List")

if(var in ('a', 'b')):
  print("Tuple")

if(var in {'a', 'b'}):
  print("Dictionary")
```

But, which data structure *should* be used here?

Comment: thats a set, not a dict. the `{}` alone are not enough to call something a dict. As for what should be used, set/dict lookups are fast. but those structures take more memory to store. So, decide accordingly.

Comment: the third option is actually a `set`, not a `dictionary`

Comment: What is the purpose of the program ?

Comment: You should invest some time in learning how to [time](https://www.pythoncentral.io/time-a-python-function/) stuff like this and investigate [resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html) [useage](https://www.fullstackpython.com/monitoring.html). Decide after that and ask questions if you're still curious as to what to do.

Comment: for two values I'd use a tuple

Comment: For only two values, I would just write `var == 'a' or var == 'b'`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that over two elements, you won't really notice a speed difference, so I'd pick the smallest of the structures, `tuple`

```sh
python -m timeit '"a" in ("a","b")'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0216 usec per loop

python -m timeit '"a" in ["a","b"]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0218 usec per loop

python -m timeit '"a" in {"a","b"}'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0255 usec per loop
```

To show a size difference between the different structures:

```py
import sys 

sys.getsizeof(('a','b'))
64

sys.getsizeof(['a','b'])
80

sys.getsizeof({'a','b'})
224
```

### Edit

As @Torxed points out, there is a trade-off between memory usage and speed. For smaller groups of elements (1-10), a `tuple` or `list` is fine, but let's try with a group of 100 elements:

```sh
# -s *doesn't* get timed here
# list approach, 1 is last giving worst-case scenario
python -m timeit -s 'var = [x for x in range(100)][::-1]' '1 in var'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.947 usec per loop

# tuple approach
python -m timeit -s 'var = tuple([x for x in range(100)][::-1])' '1 in var'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.944 usec per loop

# set approach
python -m timeit -s 'var = set([x for x in range(100)][::-1])' '1 in var'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0272 usec per loop
```

You get a *massive* boost from `dict`/`set` in this case, and that's when you would forego the memory overhead in favor of speed

Comment: It's extremely important to note this: Some data structures are *great* for enumerables up to 5-10 items (lists, tuples) etc. Where as some structures will excel at greater numbers (dicts are great for larger quantities). Timing different amount of data-lengths is key here in deciding what types to use IMO.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! And you're right, for 2 elements both the size and speed is probably negligible -- but this is very interesting info for any cases in the future with much larger sizes. Thanks!

Comment: @Aziz Know that in earlier Python versions, tuples are superior up to 5-10 elements, lists are fastest up until 10-50 items. After that, dicts are faster in every shape and form. Especially in accessing objects for obvious reasons. Memory consumption follow along the speed generally in this aspect. I stand by my comment above, learn to time the differences in both size and use cases.

Comment: @Torxed even in lengths up to 100 elements, I haven't noticed a significant performance gain in a `list` over a `tuple` (~1%). However, at this size, you are correct, `dict` and `set` are far and away *much* better options. I'll add an edit in my answer to highlight your point

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the last option is not a dictionary, it's a set. Think of it as a KeyValuePair<> if you come from a C# background.

Secondly. A tuple is quite faster when being assigned as it is immutable and can be compacted easily.

Comment: set is nothing like a KeyValuePair in C#? I'm rusty in C#, but what you described is actually a dict in C#?

Comment: Mutability doesn't really matter for an object that gets garbage-collected immediately.